# Playframework I believe is using java 7, I'm getting Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I'm using playframework 2.2.2 on OSX.

My command line reports I am using the following java version:

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

I'm using tomcat jdbc pool, and when I load my play app I get this error:

```
[RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/tomcat/jdbc/pool/PoolConfiguration : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0]
```

Now correct me if I am wrong, but I believe somehow play uses its own java version, which is java 7 correct?   I remember seeing this outputted somewhere when using play but I can seem to figure out where I saw this.

So what is the issue here, is it that play is compiling using java 7 but when I run it is using version 6?

Note: I don't use the play command to run my app, rather I use `sbt` to enter b/c I have several projects and I then just type `run`.

My project layout in sbt is:

```
common
services
web <-- play app
```

How can I fix this issue as I am a little lost what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Play 2.2 is compatible with Java 6 and 7. Play itself doesn't ship with Java so your build will be picking up a version of Java that's already on your system.

Here's the logic inside the `play` command. As you can see, `play` uses the version of Java in the path or the version within `JAVA_HOME`.

```
if [ -z "$JAVA_HOME" ]; then
  JAVA="java"
else
  JAVA="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"
fi
```

Since you're getting a runtime error with a Tomcat class, I think it's most likely not a Play compile problem. My guess is that you're using a version of Tomcat that requires Java 7 or higher, such as Tomcat 8. See [Apache Tomcat Versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) for more info.

By the way, you can configure SBT/Play to make sure it always generates Java 6 bytecode by giving the Java compiler some options:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.6", "-target", "1.6")
```

See [SBT's Java Sources docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Java-Sources.html).

Comment: great that was the reason, version 8 required java7.  btw, for a new project is it recommended to use java7? i.e. performance wise it is better?

Comment: I'd probably use Java 7, but that's not an "official" recommendation. :)

Comment: BTW, I think you can mark this as the answer if it solves your problem.